# BASH сравнение переменных по строкам в CSV

Tags: bash, csv

Идея такова- есть такой файл:

`Interworking - unspecified,127,1,2016/04/06 17:40,EMPTY,RNC1
Call rejected,21,2,2016/04/06 17:40,EMPTY,RNC1
Call rejected,21,2,2016/04/06 17:40,EMPTY,RNC2
User alerting - no answer,19,176,2016/04/06 17:40,EMPTY,RNC3
No circuit/channel available,34,2,2016/04/06 17:40,EMPTY,RNC4
Call rejected,21,6,2016/04/06 17:40,EMPTY,RNC5`

Нужно вычислить сумму значений третьей переменной из строк, в которых вторая переменная равна Х (Например, 21).
Далее, при превышении установленного значения максимальной суммы третьей переменной (Например, не должна превышать 10) производится отправка всех строк участвующих в расчёте на e-mail администратору.

Comment: *эту строку* — уточните у преподавателя, которую из двух.

Comment: тут нужно сравнение с числом и если полученный результат выше числа, тогда нужно скинуть все строки которые содержат параметр 2й параметр(2стоблец), т.е. допустип в данном примере нужно скинуть первую и вторую строку.

Comment: и что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: В прицепе ничего, смог только просумировать количество значений 3й колонки при условии совпадения значения во 2, но в итоге дальше не смогу продвинуться, не знаю что делать. Просьба помочь.

Comment: вы получили несколько сумм. насколько я понял, вам надо выбрать из них максимальную.

Comment: Не) Идея такова

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
#!/bin/bash
#CONSTANTS
MAIL_SUBJECT="Превышение значения"
MAIL_TO="admin@domain.com"
ZANCHENIE="10"

#Получаем все нужные строки со вторыми переменными равными "ZNACHENIE"

cat /root/file.input | grep .*\,$ZNACHENIE

#Здесь производим нужные вычисления - вы указали
#что смогли получить сумму третьих переменных

if [[ $summa -gt $porog ]]; then
cat /root/file.input | grep .*\,$ZNACHENIE >> /root/StringsToSend
echo $MAIL_SUBJECT | cat - /root/StringsToSend | sendmail -t $MAIL_TO
fi
```

Comment: #!/bin/bash
LDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","
echo "\n" >> RNC_Rel.csv<br/>
for i in 19 31 41 57 65 81 98 8 21 28 30 38 63 70 99 25 55 88 102 3 22 26 27 47 69 79 91 29 34 42 87 96 1 50 95 97 111 127 6 43 44 68 58 100 101
do
eval sum$i=0
while read ccname cccode sumtran time rabcouse rncname<br/>
do
    if [ "$cccode" -eq "$i" ];
then
eval sum$i=$((sum$i+$sumtran))
fi
done < $1
if eval ["$`echo sum$i`" -gt "100"  -a "$cccode" -eq "31"];
then
echo "CC Code $i"
eval echo "Sum Tran"   $`echo sum$i`
fi
done
IFS=$OLDIFS `

Comment: @Pavel, Что это? У Вас явно проблемы с форматированием текста.

Comment: что-то я никак не въеду как тут коменты форматировать :) Это та часть скрипта которая получает сумму 3х переменных исходя из схожести 2й. у меня не получается переменную $`echo sum$i` внести в сравнение оператора if. Возможно Вы можете предложить другой вариант сравнения нежели мой?

Comment: если есть возможность, откройте личку в ВК, будет проще. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

> смог только просумировать количество значений 3й колонки при условии совпадения значения во 2, но в итоге дальше не смогу продвинуться, не знаю что делать.

дальше надо сравнить эту сумму с «пороговым» значением.

примерно так:

```
if [[ $summa -gt $porog ]]; then
  нужные действия
fi
```

`-gt` — «больше, чем». если надо «больше или равно», то используйте `-ge`. см. `man bash`.

Comment: Не) Идея такова есть такой файл <br> Interworking - unspecified,127,1,2016/04/06 17:40,EMPTY,RNC1 <br>
Call rejected,21,2,2016/04/06 17:40,EMPTY,RNC1 <br>
Call rejected,21,2,2016/04/06 17:40,EMPTY,RNC2 <br>
User alerting - no answer,19,176,2016/04/06 17:40,EMPTY,RNC3 <br>
No circuit/channel available,34,2,2016/04/06 17:40,EMPTY,RNC4 <br>
Call rejected,21,6,2016/04/06 17:40,EMPTY,RNC5 <br> и так далее, нужно делать следующее брать 2 параметр в каждой строке например 21(тут всегда будет какое-то число, все эти числа известны если они нужны),

Comment: ищем во всем файле строки где второй параметр 21, прошлись нашли, далее нужно сложить значение во всех найденных строках 3 параметр( или столбец как будет понятнее :) ) в итоге получили значение этого сложения и допустим тут будет условие такое для каждого значения из второго столбца (параметра) будет свое предельное значение суммы третьего столбца, допустим в этом случае будет 5, т.е. сложив все значения по параметру второго столбца 21,

Comment: получаем сумму третьего столбца 10, значит этот параметр превысил порог и нужно все строки который содержат во втором столбце 21 скинуть на email. и так нужно настроить для разных значений во втором столбце. ну как-то так) надеюсь не зря писал) сможете помочь :) Спасибо!

Comment: отлично. вы изложили фактически то же, что и я в ответе. т.е. алгоритм вам известен, но вы не знаете, как реализовать тот или иной пункт из алгоритма. задавайте **конкретные** вопросы с помощью кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Comment: @Pavel, я переписал ответ.